# null [FormBody] string value when using fetch in react

Tags: c#, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I have the following fetch in my .js file:

```
fetch('api/SampleData/GetBpmnXml', {
    method: 'post',
    
    body: {
        "first_name": "Bob"
    }
})
```

and in the API I have this Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string first_name)
{ return first_name;}
```

Why is the returned value null, and not bob?

Answer (score 0):

See the body section and the argument is named `first_name` and not `value` as in your Api endpoint. Probably change your Api endpoint to below; so that it can bind to the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string first_name)
{ return value;}
```

Comment: i fixed that but im still getting null from the post.